# facebook link after apprequest

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I'm building an FB application. I'm using the JS SDK on my website for inviting friends to my FB app.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  display: 'iframe',
  access_token: resp.accessToken,
  message: 'Please join Bashman'
}, function(response){
  //nothing important here
});
```

When I invite some FB friend, then on their notification bar, they have a link, that points to my app, instead to let them accept my invitation.

So the user is redirected instantly to my app instead of have the possibility to accept the invitation first.

I've made a screenshot of two app requests, the first one is not mine, it redirects as expected to the accept invitation area, it points to:

http://www.facebook.com/?sk=apps&scrollto=confirm_162129010502890&ref=notif&notif_t=app_request

The next one is from my FB app, and it points directly to mine app, instead of the acceptation area:

http://apps.facebook.com/orgbashman/?request_ids=293075284044707%2C182589535157904&ref=notif&notif_t=app_request
[image]

I tried to use also the

> redirect_uri

parameter

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  display: 'iframe',
  access_token: resp.accessToken,
  message: 'Please join Bashman',
  redirect_uri: 'http://www.facebook.com/sk=apps&scrollto=confirm_134863713284095&ref=notif&notif_t=app_request',
}, function(response){
  //nothing important here
});
```

but without luck.

How I can make the link in the notification area point to the accept FB app button instead of pointting directly to my FB app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rewriting the blog post made by Facebook, I'm just going to link to it:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

I tested this out with an app I'm building and I got the same results as you. But as soon as I disabled `Upgrade to Requests 2.0` in the `Advanced section` when editing the app settings, the requests worked exactly as you want them to.

And here's a detailed explanation on what possibilities Requests 2.0 provide:

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/02/16/facebook-introduces-upgrade-to-requests-2-0-to-simplify-re-engagement/